# form validation always returns false

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the following method in a controller and i invoke the call to this method by doing the following

```
  <?php
class dcode {
    public $api_url = 'http://www.jasafollower.com/apii/'; // API URL
    public $api_key = 'bXV6Z2ttNzNkUysyb1dlcmlpL2FuZz09'; // SECRET KEY
    public $api_id = '745b10-edd123-8d71b3-cd2187-f48a74'; // API KEY

    public function profile() {
        return json_decode($this->connect($this->api_url.'profile', array('api_key' => $this->api_key, 'api_id' => $this->api_id)));
    }

    public function services() {
        return json_decode($this->connect($this->api_url.'services', array('api_key' => $this->api_key, 'api_id' => $this->api_id)));
    }

    public function order($data) {
        return json_decode($this->connect($this->api_url.'order', array_merge(array('api_key' => $this->api_key, 'api_id' => $this->api_id), $data)));
    }

    public function status($order_id) {
        return json_decode($this->connect($this->api_url.'status', array('api_key' => $this->api_key, 'api_id' => $this->api_id, 'id' => $order_id)));
    }

    private function connect($end_point, $post) {
        $_post = Array();
        if (is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $name => $value) {
                $_post[] = $name.'='.urlencode($value);
            }
        }
        $ch = curl_init($end_point);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        if (is_array($post)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, join('&', $_post));
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump($result);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0 && empty($result)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}

$api = new dcode();

// cek profil
$profile = $api->profile();
var_dump($profile);
print('<br /><br />');
```

here is the method

```
public function profile() {
        // filter input = 1
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $result = ['status' => false, 'data' => 'Permintaan salah'];
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('api_id', 'API ID', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('api_key', 'API KEY', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
```

I am pulling out my hair on figuring out why form_validation->run() always returns false here.. any idea why ?

Comment: I don't know CI that well, but normally when you send data to PHP with `application/json`, the super global `$_POST` isn't populated (which I assume that CI uses for the form validation). You need to manually fetch the body of the request and decode the json.

Comment: [codeigniter-form-validation-run-always-returns-false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000803/codeigniter-form-validation-run-always-returns-false) might help

Comment: @berend - The reason it didn't work in that post was because they hadn't set any rules, which the OP here clearly has. It's always good to make sure that the questions/answers are relevant/the same, not just the title.

Answer (score 0):

You did not load the form_validation library:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```